# Problem with MPI_Gather Couldnt gather 8 arrays of 32 element into a big array of 256 elements

Tags: c++, mpi, hpc

i am new to MPI , i have an array of 256 integer , i want to divide each number by 16 , I suggested to Scatter 32 element on each Processor but i couldn't gather them as each Return value contains array of 32

```
int globalhistogram[256];
float globalProb[256];
float* localprob = new float[32];
int localpixel[32];

MPI_Scatter(&globalhistogram, 32, MPI_INT, localpixel, 32, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
  localprob[i] = (float)localpixel[i] / 16;
}

MPI_Gather(localprob, 32, MPI_FLOAT, &globalprob, 32, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: In your scatter call, change `&globalhistogram` to `histogram` and in your gather call, change `&globalprob` to `globalprob`. You're going one indirection level too far: `globalprob` is already the buffer address.

Comment: you are running 8 MPI tasks, right?

Comment: Yes 8 Tasks , i want to gather the output of each task in one array , but each one return an array of 32 element

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the issue - the code appears to run correctly after I correct what I assume is a typo `float globalProb[256]` -> `float globalprob[256]`.

I agree with @victor-eijkhout about the `&globalprob` issue but it doesn't appear to make a difference.

If I compile and run the appended code I get the expected answer:

```
dsh@laptop$ mpicxx -o play play.cpp 
dsh@laptop$ mpirun -n 8  ./play
rank 0: globalprob[0] = 0.000000
...
rank 0: globalprob[31] = 31.000000
rank 0: globalprob[32] = 64.000000
...
rank 0: globalprob[255] = 2040.000000
```

Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(void)
{
  int rank, size, i;

  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

  int globalhistogram[256];
  float globalprob[256];
  float* localprob = new float[32];
  int localpixel[32];

  for (i=0; i < 256; i++)
    {
      globalhistogram[i] = i;
    }

  MPI_Scatter(&globalhistogram, 32, MPI_INT, localpixel, 32, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
      localprob[i] = (float)localpixel[i] *(rank+1);
    }

  MPI_Gather(localprob, 32, MPI_FLOAT, &globalprob, 32, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if (rank == 0)
    {
      for (i=0; i < 256; i++)
        {
          printf("rank %d: globalprob[%d] = %f\n", rank, i, globalprob[i]);
        }
    }
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```